# Jmeter's proxy server does not record

Tags: proxy, jmeter, neoload

New to JMeter. I have downloaded and configured proxy server as the step by step guide from JMeter website. Got right log message such as "protocol 8080 has been created" and "Proxy is up running" etc. But it just did not record localhost:8080 with Tomcat. Change to Neoload to record localhost:8080 and everything works fine but JMeter just does not record anything. There is no errors in the log or within the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the proxy ?
Try stopping it to see if you get an error in browser.
Are you sure neoload is not already listening to this same port and jmeter could not start on this same one.

Finally you could try using your ip in browser address.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what mistake have you made. This is what you can do from scratch:

1. Create empty plan
2. Add HTTP Proxy Server to WorkBench
3. In its configuration set port to free one at your computer (maybe 8080 is busy). Click Start
4. Set browser proxy to localhost, choose the same port as in JMeter's proxy
5. Browse to any url

--> Samplers should appear in JMeter

You may also like to change Target Controller so samplers will appear in more appropriate place